# How do I retrieve a JSON encoded array printed inside a <div> from a JavaScript file?

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, json

I know that this question might have been asked like 100 times, but, believe me, I checked a lot for already asked questions and I could not find a proper answer for my case.

Basically what I would like to do is pass an array my PHP code is generating to a separate JavaScript file which will do something with it. Nothing new untill now, I suppose, so let me give you some clarification specific for my case. Let's say I am a bit ahead.

I found many answers that suggested to just pass the encoded version of my array echoing it out inside my PHP file and then retreiving it from the separate JavaScript file.

I was going to use this method but what I encountered is that I can't go for `getJSON()` method because I have my encoded array inside a PHP file that outputs something more that just that.

So my final question would be: **How can I retrieve, from my separate JavaScript file, my json_encoded version of the array from my PHP file?**

And note again that I have my array echoed inside a  (occasionally made `style="visibility:hidden"` for the purpose of not showing it to the user).

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**
Ok thanks for the answers. Probably i wasnt clear enough with all the details.

My program is made up of, let's say, 3 files.

1)HTML file with a form and a submit button->action send the data to the php file i was mentioning.

```
<form name="foo" action="foo.php" method="GET">
<input type="text" name="footext"/>
<input type="submit" value="Send Data"/>
```

2)PHP file which get the data from the previous form, process it and ultimately create the array i have to take into consideration

something that uses the `$_GET['footext']` and produces `$array` in the end and of course, as i metioned earlier I was trying to solve this with

```
echo "<div style=\"display:none\">" . json_encode($array) . "</div>";
```

3)JS file which does something else, or will do, considering that everything in thit script is based on what i retrieve from my php array.

here i prepared some functions and tested them with a static array but what i need is to, obviously, retrieve `$array` from the previous file and use it instead of a bogus one

Comment: Code? Also, use `display:none` instead of `visibility:hidden`. The first option will really hide the div, while the `visibility:hidden` style only makes the content invisible, while preserving space.

Comment: thanks and sorry, i am a bit new to this :)

Comment: Can't you do this? `"<script language='javascript'> var array =". json_encode($array) . "; doSomethingWith(array);</script>"`

Comment: so to achieve that if i am not wrong i need to:
1)add that line of code inside my foo.php and include my js file in it
2)modify my js function so that accepts the array as parameter

Comment: Yes. This should work, if I understood your problem correctly.

Comment: I think it worked, but this brought me up another question which is quite a consequence of this solution, i don't really know if i should post another question or just ask it right here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions for this problem. First is to put that array/json-encoding generation code in another PHP file and get it via AJAX (getJSON) separately. Second is to put the contents of the output in a pre-processed format for Jquery, hide it in an random element and get its contents via jQuery selector. The first one is more simple and elegant, I'd implement it.